# Modern Minecraft Bedrock Edition Modding

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-mods, minecraft-addons

I started playing MCPE back at alpha 0.9.5 and have followed development of the game and modding since. The old school way was Blocklauncher and ModPe javascript, and it worked great. But now, Blocklauncher is no longer in development, and even if it is, it no longer manages to keep up with the fast updates.

What options do I have to retain the modding capabilities of the old days? Toolbox for MCPE doesn't seem to be able to execute ModPe javascript, addons (last I heard) are more limited compared to the old ModPe javascript, and the official scripting API is still in beta and only for Win10, which I don't have (I have Android).

Any ideas?

Thank you for your time.

---

Edit:

My end goal is to be able to run a multiplayer world on Android. Originally thought of this modding limitation, so looked at Geyser, running a Java server for Bedrock, but it turns out Geyser doesn't support Fabric, which is needed for modding. Thus, I'm now looking for a way to get mods to work like they used to on Android. If anyone has a better idea to achieve my end goal, that would also be welcome.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: What kind of stuff are you doing? Because while addons used to be pretty trash, have a lot of capabilities now

Comment: @Penguin I'm looking to recreate a video series by a certain Youtuber, but they played on Java, while I only have Bedrock. Aside from that, I would really like to record on mobile, but if it's not possible I guess I'll have to go to Java. As for the modding itself, I'm thinking of starting with Lucky Blocks, which means adding a custom block (not editing an existing one), having triggers for it when broken, having data values, custom items and entities, etc... You get the idea I guess.

Comment: on Android can you easily create and write files (like `.json` files)?

Comment: @Penguin Yes, I can create and write such files relatively easily. The fact that a phone has a small screen is just a minor nuisance, if it gets in the way I can write elsewhere.

Comment: @Penguin I may be missing something, but I can not attach custom code to my addons. On the contrary, ModPe was able to do practically anything. Any suggestions on what else I can try?

Comment: you can make lucky blocks with addons, many already have and thats like 90% of all addons because a lot of people start with lucky blocks and they get downloads. [There are 126 lucky block addons on MCPEDL alone](https://mcpedl.com/?s=lucky+blocks)

Comment: @Penguin Oof, I somehow managed to forget about MCPEDL...thanks for the reminder! I took a look at one of them, and damn do they look different to how it used to be done back during the days of ModPe... which kinda makes me question, do you think everything that can be done with ModPe can be pulled off with the addons system as well? Thank you for your assistance so far!

Comment: I'd say most things now can probably be done with a combination of Functions + Addons

Comment: @Penguin I see, thanks for the assistance!